# Amazon custom AMI retain old hostname / ip address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I've created a custom Amazon AMI but I've noticed that when I launch it it reports the wrong hostname and in some app even the wrong private IP.

The problem seems that it is retained the network configuration. For example the command:

> $ hostname
>   ip-10-80-159-25.eu-west-1.compute.internal

But the ifconfig command report the following:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 22:00:0A:24:D3:28  
          inet addr:10.36.211.40  Bcast:10.36.211.63  Mask:255.255.255.192
          inet6 addr: fe80::2000:aff:fe24:d328/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:109917 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:38495 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:511805711 (488.0 MiB)  TX bytes:4716923 (4.4 MiB)
          Interrupt:33
```

Actually in the file `/etc/sysconfig/network` I've noticed that it is retained the old instance hostname.

Any clue what is happening? When I launch a new instance it should be assigned with a new hostname, shouldn't it?

Comment: you might check /etc/hosts settings.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that in the file `/etc/sysconfig/network` the was the following line:

```
HOSTNAME=ip-10-80-159-25.eu-west-1.compute.internal
```

I've fixed replacing it with the following one:

```
HOSTNAME=localhost.localdomain
```